# How do I print to PDF in Microsoft Word as a grayscale?

Tags: pdf, ms-word

I have a document in Microsoft Word that I want to save as a PDF on my computer in grayscale. How do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can accomplish that without other tools like the free [PDFCreator](https://www.pdfforge.org/)

After installing it, you can select it as a printer. For grayscale you will have to enable this option:
[image]